# How to update a p:chart dynamically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts, pie-chart

I want to dynamically show the data from my database in a pie chart. To show only data, is no problem, but if the number increases, the pie doesn't update.I have no idea how to update the chart. I use the PrimeFaces library.

So here is my main code for this problem:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Chart implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private PieChartModel pieModel1;
    private int n = 0;
    private int j = 0;
    private int s = 0;
    private List<Erfasst> erfassungen;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("CP Kontrolle");

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        createPieModels();
    }

    private void createPieModels() {
        pieModel1 = new PieChartModel();
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Erfasst e");
        erfassungen = q.getResultList();

        for (Erfasst erf : erfassungen) {
            if (erf.getRechtsform().equals("natürliche Person")) {
                n++;
            } else if (erf.getRechtsform().equals("juristische Person")) {
                j++;
            } else {
                s++;
            }
        }

        pieModel1.set("natürliche Personen", n);
        pieModel1.set("juristische Personen", j);
        pieModel1.set("sonstige", s);

        pieModel1.setTitle("Erfassungen gesamt");
        pieModel1.setLegendPosition("e");
        pieModel1.setFill(false);
        pieModel1.setShowDataLabels(true);
        pieModel1.setDiameter(150);
    }

    public PieChartModel getPieModel1() {
        return pieModel1;
    }
}
```

And on the view side:

```
<p:chart type="pie"
         model="#{chart.pieModel1}"
         style="width:400px;height:300px"
         styleClass="chartPie" id="aufstellung" />
```

Comment: And where do you udate the chart?

Comment: This is exact my question

Comment: No, your statement was that it doesn't get updated, but if you do not tell it to update, it never will. Updating a chart (via ajax) is identical to updating any othe jsf component (via ajax). Lots of examples on that on ths internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not update automatically in default configuration (you have to update it "manually"). However, you can combine chart with PrimePush (websocket).

A good example is at PF showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chart.xhtml (push chart)

Comment: If you answer, can you please add some detail? Or better yet, find a 'duplicate' that is about updating in general

Comment: With the inspiration of James i update my chart with the <p:poll /> tag. Thanks at all for help